# natbib: how to display partial authors in reference

Tags: natbib, author-number

I am using `natbib` to manage my references, now I have a problem: my reference list always displays all author names of an article:

```
Marcel H. Schulz, Daniel R. Zerbino, Martin Vingron, and Ewan Birney. Oases: robust
de novo RNA-seq assembly across the dynamic range of expression levels. Bioinformatics
(Oxford, England), 28(8):1086–1092, April 2012. 7, 9, 10, 40
```

I set the options to be:

```
\usepackage[round, sort, numbers]{natbib}

\bibliographystyle{Latex/Classes/PhDbiblio-url2} 
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References} 
\bibliography{9_backmatter/references}
```

And use `cite{}` to cite the references. I tried to used `biblatex`, but seems it is not compatible with `natbib`:

```
\usepackage[maxnames=3]{biblatex}
```

I want to display at most 3 authors in full name, otherwise display as `et al.` How to set it?

================

Edit: The file PhDbiblio-url2.bst can be found here: https://bitbucket.org/dekz/thesis/src/3f8d8507cddc/Latex/Classes/PhDbiblio-url2.bst

It seems like the lines here define the display of authors:

```
INTEGERS { nameptr namesleft numnames }

FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
    { namesleft #1 >
        { ", " * t * }
        { numnames #2 >
        { "," * }
        'skip$
          if$
          t "others" =
        { " et~al." * }
        { " and " * t * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
    't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}
```

But how to set the `numnames` from the `tex` file?

Comment: How many authors are included in a citation and/or in an entry in the references section before the list is truncated to `firstauthor et al` is determined not by `natbib` but by the bibliography style file you load. Please provide a link to the file `PhDbiblio-url2.bst`; it doesn't seem to be available on the CTAN.

Comment: @Mico. Thanks. The file is this: https://bitbucket.org/dekz/thesis/src/3f8d8507cddc/Latex/Classes/PhDbiblio-url2.bst

Comment: One more question: *How* would you like to truncate the list of authors if there are more than three of them: Do you want to show just the first author followed by "et al", do you want to show the first three authors followed by "et al", or some other method?

Comment: @Mico. Yes, I would like to get something like `Marcel H. Schulz, et al. Oases: robust
de novo RNA-seq assembly across the dynamic range of expression levels....`

Comment: If anyone else would like to use this `.bst`, you shall need to include `hyperref` to get things to work properly.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe that you need to set the number of authors before `et al.` in the `.bst` itself, rather than from the LaTeX.

I think the below does what you want, I have adapted it from a `.bst` I created using [`makebst`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib). Just replace `format.names` in your [`.bst`](https://bitbucket.org/dekz/thesis/src/3f8d8507cddc/Latex/Classes/PhDbiblio-url2.bst).

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f{.}.}"
      format.name$
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          nameptr #1
          #1 + =
          numnames #3
          > and
            { "others" 't :=
              #1 'namesleft := }
            'skip$
          if$
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              t "others" =
                {
                  " et~al" *
                }
                {
                  " and "
                  * t *
                }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}
```

If you want to change the number of authors before the `et al.` is used, change `#3` from three to the correct number. If you want to change the number of names that appear before `et al.` in the list, then change the `#1` following `nameptr` on the line preceding `#1 + =` from one to the correct number.

Comment: Nice! You may want to state explicitly, even though it's probably obvious to the initiated, that one should replace the existing `format.names` function in the `.bst` file with the version you're providing.

Comment: In case anybody else needs to see this, you should make a copy of your existing `.bst` file (let's say it's called `bibstyle.bst`, so the copy is `bibstyle_copy.bst`), place it in your working directory, and make the edit suggested above. Then call it via `\bibliographystyle{bibstyle_copy}`.

Answer (score 4):

OK. I solved it in a stupid way. In the `bib` file, for articles with more than 3 authors, remove other authors from the list and put `others` instead. Then the Reference shows at most 3 authors and `et~al`. But anyway, it is a bit tedious.

Comment: This is not a solution, I would not recommend this....