# Truncating the number of authors in a citation call-out, using natbib citation management package and agsm bibliography style

Tags: citing, natbib, harvard-style

Does anyone know how to make sure that citation call-outs using `natbib` and `\bibliographystyle{agsm}` always show just `first author et al.` whenever there are more than two authors?

I have seen other answers to this, but none of them answer my question
(e.g. [natbib: how to display partial authors in reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127705/natbib-how-to-display-partial-authors-in-reference)).

I don't have the file  `agsm.bst` in my Sharelatex, so I'm not sure what to change.

In my case, it also appears that only random papers get cited like that (naming all the authors). And I don't want the Bibliography to shorten the citations, just when I generate a citation call-out in the text.